# How to limit non-google search engine bots crawl rate so they don't push me over an external API request limit?

Tags: php

I'm building for a client an amazon-affiliate website that uses Amazon Product API to fetch data from their catalogue.

Amazon have a 1 per sec request limit.

Google allow configuring the googlebot's  crawl rate via their Webmasters Tools, so there is no issue with them.

I need advice about how to go about treating other search engine crawl bots. 
What would be a good way to avoid as much possible, exceeding Amazon's API rate limit due to bot crawling?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to control the crawl speed by robots.txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787264/is-it-possible-to-control-the-crawl-speed-by-robots-txt)

Answer (score 0):

#### PHP

If you want to follow PHP approach, follow my [answer on php redirect url with og metatag (open graph)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22781663/2151050)

#### robots.txt

I would go with robots.txt file as it's fairly simple and saves time. Generally, all bots respect, and abide the rules in this file. Create a file named `robots.txt` (type: text/plain) with the following rules

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /path/to/dir/
```

Asterisk `*` is a wildcard indicating every user agent.

```
Disallow: /path/to/dir/
```

`Disallow` rule defines the paths you want bots not to crawl. You can have multiple lines for different user-agents.

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /path1/

User-agent: Facebookhit
Disallow: /path2/
```

Above will allow to access to `/path2/` to `Googlebot` but not `Facebookhit`, and vice versa. You can read more [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

Comment: Well, I look for bots using $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']  against a bot list, and can provide them with different page data. But what if a bot not on my list comes along?

Comment: Then, you're opted to use robots.txt method.